# Webservice using SFRestAPI with Swift

Tags: ios, web-services, salesforce, salesforce-ios-sdk

I'm currently trying to make a RESTful API in Salesforce and I'm having some issues with the iOS portion. Here's the swift code I've been trying to use, however I'm getting a NOT_FOUND 404 error with the message, "The requested resource does not exist."

```
let getRequest: SFRestRequest = restAPI.performRequestWithMethod(SFRestMethodGET, path: "/services/apexrest/(service name here)/", queryParams: nil, failBlock: {
        error in
            println(error)
        }, completeBlock: {
        response in
            println(response)
    })
```

I can get other SOQL queries to work within my iOS app and the user can log in just fine, I think I might be a little off in regards to calling my Apex webservice.

Any suggestions/comments are greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution ended up being

```
var request = SFRestRequest(method: SFRestMethodGET,    path:"/services/apexrest/CustomRestWebservice/", queryParams:nil)

request.endpoint = ""

restAPI.sendRESTRequest(request, failBlock: {error in println(error)}, completeBlock: { response in println(response) })﻿
```

the endpoint defaults to a string that isn't what you want, so you have to set it to nothing manually in order to get the right results.